# oracle: inter string by parameter and process it

Tags: string, oracle, oracle11g, substr

I want to read a string from user then separate words every space character in the string I have this

```
    declare
--counter1 number:=1;
--counter2 number:=1;
--instruction varchar(100);
str varchar2(100):= &inter;
begin
--while true
--loop
--instruction:=substr(str,counter,count2);
--counter2:=counter2+1;
--counter1:=counter1+1;
--exit when instruction = '% ';
--end loop;
SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(str);
end;
```

but it gives me

```
    Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 21:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TEST_STRING' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 14, column 26:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 14, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

and also the `exit when instruction = '% ';` seems too wrong to me how can I stop on space character

Answer (score 1):

So this error ...

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 21:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TEST_STRING' must be declared
```

... is probably down to this declaration:

```
str varchar2(100):= &inter;
```

Even though you are passing a substitution variable you still need to declare the assignment properly, as a string.  Like this

```
str varchar2(100):= '&inter';
```

---

Anyway, here is a pure SQL solution.

```
with cte as 
   ( select 'oracle: inter string by parameter and process it' as str
     from dual )
select regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) as word
from cte
connect by level <= regexp_count(str, chr(32))+1
/
```

The CONNECT BY is a useful trick to generate a rowset on the fly.  Here is the output:

```
SQL> with cte as ( select 'oracle: inter string by parameter and process it' as str
  2            from dual )
  3  select regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) as word
  4  from cte
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(str, chr(32))+1
  6  /  

WORD
------------------------------------
oracle:
inter
string
by
parameter
and
process
it

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using code similar to:

```
declare
  counter1 number:=1;
  counter2 number:=1;
  instruction varchar(100);
  str varchar2(100):= 'declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete';
begin
while counter1<length(str) loop
  while true loop
    instruction := substr(str, counter1, counter2);
    counter2 := counter2 + 1;
    exit when instruction like '% ' or counter1+counter2-1>length(str);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(trim(instruction));
  counter1 := counter1 + counter2-1;
  counter2 := 1;
end loop;
end;
```

... which gives this output:

```
declaration
of
the
type
of
this
expression
is
incomplete
```

It can also be done in several other ways, especially with using function [instr()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) or with regular expressions or with `connect by` in sql.
You were close, but in your code you did: `when instruction = '% '` and should be `like '% '` and you unnecessarily increased counter1 in each iteration.